# Stream audio from named pipe

Tags: bash, audio

I have a [small Python library](http://jdan.github.io/Melopy/) for audio experimentation, and currently the library writes raw wave data to the disk, which I can then feed into something like `afplay` to play the sound.

I'm curious, however, if I can play audio right from memory. I tried creating a named pipe (since `afplay` requires a filename as it's first argument), but unfortunately it is throwing the error `Error: AudioFileOpen failed ('typ?')`.

Is there an easy way to stream audio from a named pipe? Is there a better way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/)'s play or [FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/)'s ffplay.

Example with sox:

```
yourcommand | play -t wav  -
```

The argument to `-t` depends on the type audio output your command does.

Example for ffplay:

```
yourcommand | ffplay -
```

Similarly with named pipes:

```
mkfifo /tmp/fifo
yourcommand > /tmp/fifo

sox -t wav /tmp/fifo  ## on another shell or terminal
```