# live detect DTMF code from the mic using sox and multimon-ng

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, sox, dtmf

I want to detect the DTMF tones from the live audio stream.
I am able to record the live audio and store it to a wave file using sox:

```
sox -b 16 -e signed-integer -c 1 -d -t wavpcm tt.wav
```

I am also able to detect the tone using multimon-ng:

```
multimon-ng -t wav -a DTMF tt.wav
```

but when I connect the two it didn't work:

```
sox -b 16 -e signed-integer -c 1 -d -t wavpcm - | multimon-ng -t wav -a DTMF -
```

Please help me in completing this flow - live record audio + detect DTMF tone + print the character code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this, but this is what came to mind is to use a named pipe

```
mkfifo ~/fifo

sox -b 16 -e signed-integer -c 1 -d -t wavpcm ~/fifo &

multimon-ng -t wav -a DTMF ~/fifo
```

It looks like it has been solved in a similar way before:

[Stream audio from named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744710/stream-audio-from-named-pipe)